# How can this endpoint respond a 404 status code?

Tags: asp.net-core, http-status-code-404, http-status-codes

I have this method in one controller of my **ASP.NET Core** application:

```
[HttpPost("my-method")]
[Authorize(Policies.ADMIN, AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public async Task<ActionResult<bool>> MyMethod()
{
    try
    {
        await DoWork();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex, "Error while doing work");
        return StatusCode(500, false);
    }

    return Ok(true);
}
```

However, sometimes I get a 404 response when calling this endpoint. When I look at the logs, I see this:

- 15:54:37.334: Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST https://myurl/my-method application/x-www-form-urlencoded 0
- 15:54:37.351: Successfully validated the token.
- 15:54:37.351: Request finished in 18.0889ms **404**

So the endpoint is found, the bearer token is validated... and yet there it is the 404 response. **But how can it be?** I'd say that the only possible output codes from my method are 200 and 500, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a test and can reproduce same issue if it does not match any action. And in my view, the log `"Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST https://myurl/my-method..."` just indicates that the request is incoming and server starts processing it, not mean that the endpoint is found and it hits your controller action method.

*Controller and Action*

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[Authorize]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost("my-method")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<bool>> MyMethod()
    {        
        //...

        return Ok(true);
    }

}
```

*Make a POST request*

```
POST https://localhost:5001/my-method
```

*Logs*

[image]

*Make request to `api/values/my-method`, which works well*

```
POST https://localhost:5001/api/values/my-method
```

So please check if you apply `[Route(...)]` to your controller and please make sure you make request with correct URL path.